# Only Show Text on Selection - MUI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I only want to show the text of the tab on selection.
This is from the MUI documentation. How can I only show labels on selection? I assume I can use the state below and translate it somehow, how on the selection the color appears with the element.

Please see the code where I have tried to establish. I am new to this framework. If anyone can provide tips let me know!

```
function TabPanel(props) {
    const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;
  
    return (
      <div
        role="tabpanel"
        hidden={value !== index}
        id={`vertical-tabpanel-${index}`}
        aria-labelledby={`vertical-tab-${index}`}
        {...other}
      >
        {value === index && (
          <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
            <Typography>{children}</Typography>
          </Box>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  TabPanel.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  };
  
  function a11yProps(index) {
    return {
      id: `vertical-tab-${index}`,
      'aria-controls': `vertical-tabpanel-${index}`,
    };
  }

//

const JobPostBuild = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue);
    };
  
    return (
      <Box
        sx={{ flexGrow: 1, bgcolor: 'gray', display: 'flex', height: 500 }} 
      >
       <Tabs
        orientation="vertical"
        variant="scrollable"
        centered
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        sx={{ borderRight: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}
      >
        <Tab icon={<WorkIcon/>} label={"Role"} {...a11yProps(0)} />
        <Tab icon={<AccountBoxIcon/>} label="People" {...a11yProps(1)} />
        <Tab icon={<ViewCompactIcon/>} label="Build" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        <Tab icon={<PostAddIcon/>} label="Post" {...a11yProps(3)} />

      </Tabs>

      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Role
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        People
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Build
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={3}>
        Post
      </TabPanel>

    </Box>
    );
  }

export default JobPostBuild
```

Happy to discuss this over Discord please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `value` of selected tab to set a condition for displaying tab label:

`<Tab label={value === 0 ? "Role" : ""} {...a11yProps(0)} />`

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hide-tab-label-js58d?file=/demo.tsx:1277-1336)

Comment: Thankyou @Dmitriif! This works as I expected. I also tried to center the tabs in the navbar however it doesn't seem to work if orientation=vertical. Any ideas

Comment: You should add  `variant="fullWidth"` to your `Tabs` component to center the elements.  I've just modified my demo to show it.

Comment: Hi Dmitriff, it doesn't seem to centre the tab section against the the remainder of the container. Please see reference pic, similar to an align-items center so that it sits in the center against the remainder of the component: https://gyazo.com/a99ce5229bf3139d0a1d4bbc79d045a5

Comment: Then you should specify the height of the tabs container and center elements as you normally do inside it. See the demo.

Comment: Lifesaver! Thankyou so much Dmitriff. I really appreciate the help!! Honestly the best, thankyou! I'm continually learning. If you want to add my discord let me know :)